# Dependency_overrides not working while using Pytest

Tags: pytest, fastapi, pydantic

```py
# main.py 
@app.on_event("startup")
def on_startup():
    logging.info("Creating database tables")
    SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)


@app.get("/ping")
def ping(settings = Depends(get_settings)):
    return settings.DATABASE_URL
```

I import the engine in this file from the db.py file.

```py
# db.py
from sqlmodel import create_engine, Session
from app.config import get_settings


settings = get_settings() # <- Here the error occurs (1 validation error for Settings, DATABASE_URL,  Field required [type=missing, input_value={}, input_type=dict])
engine = create_engine(settings.DATABASE_URL)
```

The error occurs when instantiating the database class since it looks in the env for the variable. However, I have overwritten the get_settings function in the conftest.py file which should initiate the client first. Why am I still getting this error and how can I fix it?

```py
# config.py 
from functools import lru_cache
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    DATABASE_URL: str # Set in environment in actual container

@lru_cache
def get_settings():
    return Settings()
```

```py
# conftest.py
import pytest
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from app.config import Settings
from app.main import app


def get_settings_override():
    DATABASE_TEST_URL = "mssql+pyodbc://sa:Password123@db:1433/master?driver=ODBC+Driver+18+for+SQL+Server&Encrypt=No"
    return Settings(DATABASE_URL=DATABASE_TEST_URL)


@pytest.fixture()
def test_app():
    with TestClient(app) as test_client:
        yield test_client
```

The test itself

```py
# test_ping.py
def test_ping(test_app):
    response = test_app.get("/ping")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == "pong!"
```

Comment: You haven't included where you're overriding `get_settings`, but it's important to remember that any dependency overrides will _only_ be used when the dependency is being resolved through a `Depends` in a controller / controller dependency hierarchy. It will not change what a general function does or what it does when being called. In your call to `get_settings()` it seems like you're just calling it as a normal function, no overrides will take place in that context. You can set an environment variable for your tests instead.

Comment: Or you can request a service/etc. in your endpoint with Depends, where the function creating the service has a dependency on a database, and the function creating the database has a dependency on the `get_settings` function; in that case, an override will do what you expect.